# Having multiple pip versions?

Tags: python, pip

In Ubuntu I have Python3 as default and pip and pip3. Now I need Python2 to install an app. I have Python2 installed but not pip2. If I try

```
sudo python2 -m pip install my_app
```

or

```
sudo python2 -m pip2 install my_app
```

I get:

```
No module named pip
```

If I install pip2 via easy_install or get-pip.py will it make me problems with pip which is for Python3? What is the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely install `pip` for both py2.x and py3.x simultaneously. You can explicitly specify which pip to use by using `pip2` for py2.x or `pip3` for py3.x.

`sudo apt-get install python-pip` installs `pip2`
while
`sudo apt-get install python3-pip` installs `pip3`

also to keep things simple, just using
`sudo pip2 install my_app`
will suffice.

EDIT:
I have noticed that in some cases even `pip3` calls the python2.x interpreter. To be on a totally safe side I recommend using -
`sudo python2 -m pip install my_app` for python2.x and
`sudo python3 -m pip install my_app` for python3.x

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install python-pip`

Is a right command to my knowledge. Bit I don't think the other methods will interrupt your python3 but no experience with those.

Comment: there is no such package - `python2-pip`

Comment: Aah thanks I know for python3-pip it works as python2 is the default on my pc so I imagened if python3 was your default you'd need to add the 2 there for the non default